# Exclude specific class name from click handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I add a click handler to `<li>` elements that *don't* have a certain class?
I want to do something like this:

```
$('ul.listClass li a :not(li.thisLi)').on("click")...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:not` selector is in the wrong place, you should use it on the li.

```
$('ul li:not(.thisLi) a').on('click', ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `:not()` to the `li` part of your selector and specify the class selector you want to exclude.

```
$('ul.listClass li:not(.thisLi) a')
```

This translates to:
*Select [`<a>`] inside [`<li>` that don't have class "thisLi"] inside [`<ul>` that have class "listClass"]*

---

For reference, see jQuery's [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

> All selectors are accepted inside :not()

```js
$('ul.listClass li:not(.thisLi) a').on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({
    'background-color': 'red'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listClass">
  <li><a>Yes</a></li>
  <li><a>Yes</a></li>
  <li class="thisLi"><a>No</a></li>
  <li><a>Yes</a></li>
  <li class="thisLi"><a>No</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found an answer using jquery's .not method.

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Worked for me.

Comment: How did you implement it?